# identify suspension leak on motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, suspension

Especially after a good cleansing when there is no visual signs of a spil, I found it hard to detect problems with oil leaks/levels.
Usually I can feel low levels in a rear mono suspension when driving it. But front suspension is very hard.

Any tips on this?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're asking?  From "mono suspension" I'm guessing you're talking about a motorcycle.  By "leaks" do you mean fork oil leaking from seals (or elsewhere), or air leaking from a combination oil/air-pressurized shock such as found on Honda Prolink bikes?

Comment: I am referring to oil leaks on motorcycle.

Comment: If you provide your make/model/year various motorcycles have different ways of adjusting stiffness in the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no visible leak but the suspension still feels hard, it sounds like your motorcycle's suspension is not properly calibrated to your weight.

[Ref: How to Adjust Motorcycle Suspension](http://www.motorcyclistonline.com/howto/adjust_motorcycle_suspension/)